# Spring boot - how to decrypt env variables in yaml file?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

## Context

I got spring boot app. I'm passing to it variables like this:

```
    ...
      datasource:
          url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVER_AND_PORT}/my_db
          username: ${DB_USER}
          password: ${DB_USER_PASSWORD}
```

## Challenge

This env variables can be easily read because they are in plain text.
I want to increase security with symmetric encryption.

I looking for something that I can use in my yaml file.

```
    # example how I want to use it:
    ...
     datasource:
          url: jdbc:postgresql://#{decrypt(${DB_SERVER_AND_PORT}}/my_db
```

The only requirement for encryption is ease of doing it from shell (gitlab pipeline)

## Question

If this is possible, how to do this spring boot or spring?

Comment: Why? The environment variable is not persisted. However, how do you want to decrypt it? For symmtric decryption you need another secret. How do you want to save this other secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jasypt which provides encryption support for property sources in Spring Boot Applications:

https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot

Comment: So you use an environment variable `jasypt.encryptor.password` instead of an environment variable `DB_USER_PASSWORD`. If an environment vairable isn't secure, why is this a better approach?